# How do I delete entries from two two-column tables such that their second columns match within a certain error

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

So if I have two arrays in matlab. Let's call them locations1 and locations2

locations1

```
    1123.44977625437    890.824688325172
    1290.31273560851    5065.65794385883
    1718.10632735926    2563.44895531365
    1734.55379433782    4408.20631924691
    2050.70084480064    1214.45353443990
    2299.46239346717    3781.34694047196
    4186.02801290113    4386.67818566045
    5676.10649593031    4529.23023993815
```

locations2

```
    7474.22619378039    3166.41503120846
    8604.40241305284    5069.40744277799
    9048.25231808890    2563.58997620248
    9059.71923042408    4381.75034710351
    9643.05902166767    3796.42822996919
    11460.8617087264    4392.85930695209
```

And I want to make it so that any two entries of the second columns that match each other within 100.0 remain while any entry that has no match will get removed. So I want the output to look like

locations1

```
    1290.31273560851    5065.65794385883
    1718.10632735926    2563.44895531365
    1734.55379433782    4408.20631924691
    2299.46239346717    3781.34694047196
    4186.02801290113    4386.67818566045
```

locations2

```
    8604.40241305284    5069.40744277799
    9048.25231808890    2563.58997620248
    9059.71923042408    4381.75034710351
    9643.05902166767    3796.42822996919
    11460.8617087264    4392.85930695209
```

How would I do this? Preferably without loops. Here is what I've done, but it has loops

```
    locround1=round(locations1/50)*50;
    locround2=round(locations2/50)*50;

    for i=1:size(locations1,1)
      nodel1(i)=sum(locround1(i,2)== locround2(:,2))
    end

    nodel1=repmat(nodel1>0,[2,1]);
    nodel1=nodel1';
    locations1=nodel1.*locations1;
    locations1( ~any(locations1,2), : ) = [];

    for i=1:size(locations2,1)
      nodel2(i)=sum(locround2(i,2)== locround1(:,2))
    end

    nodel2=repmat(nodel2>0,[2,1]);
    nodel2=nodel2';
    locations2=nodel2.*locations2;
    locations2( ~any(locations2,2), : ) = [];
```

Comment: What’s wrong with loops? Don’t say they’re slow... That was true in the 1990’s.

Comment: Oh haha I thought they were slow. Good to know they're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I got. If your MATLAB version has set operators, you can do it with the following codes:

```
Li1 = ismembertol(locations1(:,2),locations2(:,2),100, 'DataScale', 1);
locations1_new = locations1 (Li1,:);
Li2 = ismembertol(locations2(:,2),locations1(:,2),100, 'DataScale', 1);
locations2_new = locations2 (Li2,:);
```

I tested it, it works.

Comment: Good idea using `ismembertol`!

Comment: But your solution requires that both matrix have the same size. I mean if the number of rows are different, then it will not work. In that case ismembertol function works. The execution time is slower than your solution.

Comment: My solution doesn’t require that... what makes you think so? You can try with the provided example

Comment: The first line of your code `m = abs(locations1(:,2)-locations2(:,2).')<=threshold;` you can not subtract two matrices if they are not of the same size. It gives the matrix dimension error.

Comment: If that happens to you it is probably because you have a version before R2016b, so no implicit expansion (and then the error will happen even if the original matrices have the same size, because I’m subtracting two vectors of different orientation). Try using bsxfun instead, as indicated in my answer.

Comment: Well, thank you for teaching me this new feature of MATLAB. After I finished my PhD in 2017, at that time I was using 2016a, I was not aware of that feature. Indeed, it is against the basic rule of linear algebra. Subtracting two matrices with different dimensions! Unbelievable. I felt a little old :) Again thanks for making me aware of this incredible feature.

Comment: That’s what Stack Overflow is for :-) I have also learned many Matlab features that way

Answer (score 2):

Let the data be defined as

```
locations1 = [
    1123.44977625437    890.824688325172
    1290.31273560851    5065.65794385883
    1718.10632735926    2563.44895531365
    1734.55379433782    4408.20631924691
    2050.70084480064    1214.45353443990
    2299.46239346717    3781.34694047196
    4186.02801290113    4386.67818566045
    5676.10649593031    4529.23023993815
    ];
locations2 = [
    7474.22619378039    3166.41503120846
    8604.40241305284    5069.40744277799
    9048.25231808890    2563.58997620248
    9059.71923042408    4381.75034710351
    9643.05902166767    3796.42822996919
    11460.8617087264    4392.85930695209
    ];
threshold = 100;
```

Then:

```
m = abs(locations1(:,2)-locations2(:,2).')<=threshold;
result1 = locations1(any(m,2),:);
result2 = locations2(any(m,1),:);
```

**How this works**:

- The first line computes a matrix with the distance between each value from the second column of `locations1` and each value from the second column of `locations2`. The distances are then compared with `threshold`, so that the matrix entries become `true` or `false`.

  This makes use of [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), introduced in R2016b. For Matlab versions before that, use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

  ```
  m = abs(bsxfun(@minus, locations1(:,2), locations2(:,2).'))<=threshold;
  ```

  Each row of the computed matrix, `m`, corresponds to a value from `locations1`; and each column corresponds to a value from `locations2`.
- The second line uses [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to select the rows of `location1` that satisfy the criterion for some value of `location2`.
- Similarly, the third line selects the rows of `location2` that satisfy the criterion for some value of `location1`.